# How to know which packages I have installed manually?

Tags: release-loki, system, apt

Where on the web is Loki's install manifest file? I want to compare it with the current build to see what I have installed?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another easy way to know the installed packages in your system.

- Please open [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) and execute `apt list --installed` to see what packages you have installed in your elementary OS.
- Please note that executing this command will give you a long list depending on your installed packages. However, if you execute `apt list --installed | less` it will wait for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be showing / loading package name one-by-one.
- Let's say you want to find something from the installed packages. You can `grep <package_name>` to achieve this. For example, `apt list --installed | grep 'language'` will list every package installed in your system with "language" keyword in its name.

And to get the list of the apps/packages you manually installed please execute, `comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)`.

Comment: This will tell me what is installed now, I want to compare this with the initial state to work out what I have installed since the original distro install.

Comment: @DaveLevy I have updated the answer with another command, executing that will give you the list of what you have installed after installing the OS.

Comment: fabulous ... just what i wanted